# Annoying, transitive-const-ness issue in D

Tags: constants, d

I'm running across a very annoying problem regarding transitive const in D.

I have the code below:

```
struct Slice(T)
{
    T items;
    size_t start, length, stride;

    this(T items, size_t start = 0, size_t length = size_t.max, size_t stride=1)
    {
        if (length == size_t.max)
        { length = 1 + (items.length - start - 1) / stride; }

        this.items = items;
        this.start = start;
        this.length = length;
        this.stride = stride;
    }

    Slice!(T) opSlice(size_t a, size_t b)
    {
        // Everything is fine here
        return Slice!(T)(items, start + a * stride, b - a, stride);
    }

    const(Slice!(T)) opSlice(size_t a, size_t b) const
    {
        // ERROR!  'items' is const(T), not T.
        return const(Slice!(T))(items, start + a * stride, b - a, stride);
    }
}
```

The trouble I'm running to is that, pretty much, the data types `const(Slice!int)` and `Slice!const(int)` and `const(Slice!const(int))` are just... *weird*.

How do I overload `opSlice` above, to return a constant copy of the current slice **which can subsequently be used like the original slice**?

In other words, let's say I have:

```
void test(in Slice!(int[]) some_slice)
{
    //...
}

void main()
{
    auto my_slice = Slice!(int[])();
    const my_const_slice = my_slice;
    test(my_slice); // succeeds
    test(my_const_slice); //succeeds
    test(my_const_slice[0 .. 1]); // fails
}
```

The code above doesn't work. What is the **best** way of making it work? (I could of course always templatize `test()`, but then all the slice variations -- `const(Slice!(Slice!const(int[])))` and such -- would grow exponentially, and confusingly so.)

### Edit:

Is there a solution that works for `struct`s *and* `class`es?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inout also works if Slice is a class:

```
class Slice(T)
{
    T items;
    size_t start, length, stride;
    this(){}
    inout this(inout T items, size_t start = 0, size_t length = size_t.max, size_t stride=1)
    {
        if (length == size_t.max)
            { length = 1 + (items.length - start - 1) / stride; }

        this.items = items;
        this.start = start;
        this.length = length;
        this.stride = stride;
    }

    inout(Slice!(T)) opSlice(size_t a, size_t b) inout{
        return new inout(Slice!T)(items, start + a * stride, b - a, stride);
    }
}

void test(in Slice!(int[]) some_slice)
{
    //...
}

void main()
{
    auto my_slice = new Slice!(int[])();
    const my_const_slice = my_slice;
    test(my_slice); // succeeds
    test(my_const_slice);//succeeds
    test(my_const_slice[0 .. 1]); // succeeds
}
```

Comment: the `inout(Slice!(T)) opSlice(size_t a, size_t b) inout` was pretty obscure, thanks for suggesting it.

Answer (score 5):

change the constructor to

```
inout this(inout T items, size_t start = 0, size_t length = size_t.max, size_t stride=1)
{
    if (length == size_t.max)
    { length = 1 + (items.length - start - 1) / stride; }

    this.items = items;
    this.start = start;
    this.length = length;
    this.stride = stride;
}
```

the [`inout`](http://d-programming-language.org/function.html#inout-functions) keyword was made for this, it lets the const-ness/immutability of a parameter propagate to the result

Comment: O___O you can use `inout` on a constructor?!

Comment: @Mehrdad I just tried it before submitting the answer and on my old v2.052 compiler it works, I think it's only for structs though

Comment: Whoa, good point. +1 for solving my *current* problem, but I'd love to know how to do it for classes as well, the next time it comes up. Thanks a lot for the answer! :)

Comment: Do _not_ trust `inout` prior to dmd 2.056. It's horribly broken prior to that. Now, it may very well work in this case exactly as suggested here, but whether or not `inout` works in a particular situation prior to 2.056 really doesn't tell you anything. You need to use at least dmd 2.056 if you want to use `inout` and have it work correctly.

Comment: @JonathanMDavis I'm forced to keep using 2.052 because I'm hired to finish a program that I build with dfl and I haven't been able to find a dfl lib that compiles with the current dmd

Comment: @ratchet freak There may be valid reasons to not upgrade to 2.056, but `inout` is very broken prior to 2.056, so I would definitely advise that you _not_ use `inout` if you can't upgrade.

Comment: @JonathanMDavis well if you'll stop complaining about my compiler and verify that this works after 2.056 (and maybe also the `inout(Slice!(T)) opSlice(size_t a, size_t b) inout` (something I tried but it didn't compile) construction)

Comment: @ratchetfreak It was not my intention to complain. It was my intention to inform you. I just tried it with 2.056, and it compiles.